# torch.cuda.is_available() returns true but torch models keep training on CPU

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, torch

I tried creating a new enviroment as shown here:
https://github.com/microsoft/computervision-recipes/blob/master/SETUP.md

and I checked cuda is running well, my gpu is detected and everything seems well. but when I fit the model nvdia-smi shows no occupation on GPU and the CPU is at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Torch requires setting Cuda device for each model and training process, you need to pass all weights and another tensors to Cuda device by hand. Like that:

```py
a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
a = a.to('cuda')
```

But in your case, maybe you need to use the method from the library. I recommend checking this one https://github.com/microsoft/computervision-recipes/blob/1bb489af757fde7c773e16fab87b24305cff4457/utils_cv/tracking/references/fairmot/trains/base_trainer.py#L32